# Terraform for multiple Get operations for API in APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure

I have created APIM , a healthcheck API and its operations.

> resource "azurerm_resource_group" "testrg" {   name     =
> "test-resources"   location = "eastus2" }

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "testApim" {
  name                = "test-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.testrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "testApi" {
  name                = "test-api"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.testApim.name
  revision            = "1"
  display_name        = "HealthCheck"
  service_url         = "<url>"
  protocols           = ["https"]
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "healthcheck" {
  operation_id        = "get"
  api_name            = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testApi.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testApim.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testrg.resource_group_name
  display_name        = "HealthCheck"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/Healthcheck"
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
}
```

I tried creating another Get api operation like below

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "testData" {
  operation_id        = "get"
  api_name            = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testApi.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testApim.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_api_management_api.testrg.resource_group_name
  display_name        = "Testdata"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/Testdata"
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
}
```

The Terraform plan shows two different modules being created and Terraform apply also showing successful. I can see the tfstate change as well for the same but in the portal I dont see the testData Operation created under healthcheck API. How to get multiple get operations created ?

I tried the code mentioned above and results were not reflecting in the Azure portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using azurerm_api_management_api_operation resource,
For each path of api create a new resource .

> Note:OperationId must be unique.
>
> **resource
> "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "testData" {
> operation_id        = "get-testData"** .....}

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-apim"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ....
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-api"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  ...
  
  .....

  depends_on = [ azurerm_api_management.example ]
}


resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "healthcheck" {
  operation_id        = "get-healthcheck"
  api_name            =azurerm_api_management_api.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api.example.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  display_name        = "HealthCheck"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/Healthcheck"
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }

depends_on = [ azurerm_api_management_api.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api_operation" "testData" {
  operation_id        = "get-testData"
 api_name            =azurerm_api_management_api.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management_api.example.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  display_name        = "Testdata"
  method              = "GET"
  url_template        = "/Testdata"
  response {
    status_code = 200
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_api_management_api_operation.healthcheck ]
}
```

[image]

**Reference:** https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_api_operation

Comment: Thank you Kavya, yes operation ID was same in my case and when I updated it , its working now.